# How to show hidden content in a printable version of a HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to convert an HTML table into pdf in javascript or jquery,
but the table will have hidden rows in the HTML but I want these hidden rows appears also in the pdf.

I was able to turn the table to pdf but the hidden rows aren't in the pdf.
the table will show some rows in the HTML then the user goes to the next page of the table. so I want all the pages of the table to appear in the pdf

here is my code in HTML and javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="tab">
        <table> 
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Job</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brian</td>
                    <td>41</td>
                        <td>Blogger</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Matt</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                        <td>Programmer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Arun</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                        <td>Writter</td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display: none">
                <td>Arun</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                        <td>Writter</td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display: none">
                <td>Arun</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                        <td>Writter</td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="display: none">
                <td>Arun</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                        <td>Writter</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Create PDF" 
            id="btPrint" onclick="createPDF()" />
    </p>
</body>
<script>
    function createPDF() {
        var sTable = document.getElementById('tab').innerHTML;

        var style = "<style>";
        style = style + "table {width: 100%;font: 17px Calibri;}";
        style = style + "table, th, td {border: solid 1px #DDD; border-collapse: collapse;";
        style = style + "padding: 2px 3px;text-align: center;}";
        style = style + "</style>";

        // CREATE A WINDOW OBJECT.
        var win = window.open('', '', 'height=700,width=700');

        win.document.write('<html><head>');
        win.document.write('<title>Profile</title>');   // <title> FOR PDF HEADER.
        win.document.write(style);          // ADD STYLE INSIDE THE HEAD TAG.
        win.document.write('</head>');
        win.document.write('<body>');
        win.document.write(sTable);         // THE TABLE CONTENTS INSIDE THE BODY TAG.
        win.document.write('</body></html>');

        win.document.close();   // CLOSE THE CURRENT WINDOW.

        win.print();    // PRINT THE CONTENTS.
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Without having tested anything: how about making the 'hidden' text color equal to the background color? White on white is still 'invisible'....

Comment: it won't appear in the pdf too @RenevanderLende

Comment: That's weird, any PDF creator API should not care about the color of the text. If there's content to 'print-to-PDF' it should print, regardles of the color of the text. From what I see is that you need to remove `style="display: none"` from the `<tr>` that use them and change it to something like `background-color: white; color: white` (create a CSS `<style>` section instead of inline coding). Be aware that `display: none` indeed does not display the content (as in 'empty HTML'), hence nothing to 'print'.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you are not actually creating a PDF.... It looks like you are creating a HTML page and then printing it (at which point I assume you print it to PDF)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are creating a PDF file in your code, instead you are just generating a HTML page in a popup window which you then print.
In that case, this is simply about using CSS to show/hide the rows are required.

**What we will do is:**

1. In your main HTML page, we create a class called "printonly" that we will use for the "hidden" rows `.printonly { display:none;}` and add this to the `<head>`
2. Add the class to the rows you want to hide, e.g. `<tr class="printonly">`

That's it!

**How this works:**

- In your main HTML page, the `.printonly` style will hide all the rows with that class assigned.
- In your popup window for printing, you are only including the contents of `<div id="tab">`, and this doesn't include the style for hiding the `.printonly` class... therefore they don't get hidden!

I've included the parts of your code that you need to modify below (leaving out the comments of course - they are not valid html comments):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> .printonly { display:none;} </style>   //<--  STEP 1. ADD THE STYLE
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tab">
            <table> 
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Job</th>
                </tr>
                // etc with the rest of your table rows that appear on the page.

                <tr class="printonly">   //<-- STEP 2. ADD THE CLASS TO THE "HIDDEN" ROWS
                    <td>Arun</td>
                    <td>39</td>
                    <td>Writter</td>
                </tr>
                // etc with the rest of your "hidden" table rows

            </table>
        </div>

        // the rest of your page, javascript etc. stays exactly the same.
    </html>
```

Comment: @Ibrahim Yousry Works fine. I didn't get the 'need to be **visible** in print' part, just the same effect (`display: none`), hence the equal color solution.

Comment: @RenevanderLende when I make it the equal color it took place in the HTML page so I had to make (position: absolute) and make it with a low z-index but it didn't show up in the pdf

Comment: the images also are not shown in the pdf, do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @IbrahimYousry Hard to tell without seeing the code :) Are they background images by any chance? It doesn't sound like it could be related to this issue, so it's best to start a new question about that problem and include just the code relating to it. I'll take a look but that way other people will also see it who might be able to help.